# ArrayField in Django model does not validate

Tags: python, django, postgresql, forms, widget

My model has an attribute:

```
regione = ArrayField(
    models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        choices=REGIONE_CHOICES
    ),
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    default=None
)
```

where `REGIONE_CHOICES` is `((0, 'opt0'), (1, 'opt1'), (2, 'opt2'))` and so on.

In my `ModelForm` for my `Model` I specify a widget for it:

```
class Meta:
    model = Mymodel
    fields = [some_fields, 'regione']
    widgets = {
        'regione': forms.SelectMultiple(choices=REGIONE_CHOICES)
    }
```

The choices are displayed correctly on the front-end and I can select multiple, but clicking submit doesn't go through, I get `Item 1 in the array did not validate` as an error in the form.

Comment: have you reached the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard to say for certain without running some code as the ArrayField errors aren't specific. My only thought from what you've provided is that your default value in the IntegerField is 0, but your choices tuple starts with 1 and therefore doesn't allow a 0 value.

Comment: 0 is a valid option, my bad for not making it clear, I edited accordingly. Besides, the default value doesn't come into play if a value is specified.